# Animate Foundation 5 Offcanvas Icon

Tags: mobile, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

i googled half a day now and tried several solutions but nothing worked for me. So YOU guys are my last chance :( 
I set up a new website using foundation5. For the mobile version i'm using the offcanvas. I'm now trying to replace the offcanvas burger or at least animate it. I think the out-of-the-box style is not really userfriendly as it doesnt indicates that it also could be used to close the offcanvas again.

I am lookig for something like here: http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/navicon-transformicons/

I allready tried it like

```
 .menu-icon.arrow.close {
  transform: scale3d(.8,.8,.8);
}

.menu-icon.arrow.close .lines{
    &:before,
    &:after {
      top: 0;
      width: $button-size/1.8;
    }

    &:before { transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,40deg); }
    &:after { transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,-40deg); }
}
```

with the button like this

```
    <section class="left-small">
        <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon lines-button arrow arrow-left" role="button" aria-label="Toggle Navigation"><span class="lines"></span></a>
    </section>
```

Any suggestions what I should do?

Comment: From the link you provided, you can add a simple script which adds/removes a "closed" class to the icon's container when clicked and then using CSS you can transform the icon as you wish.

Comment: @geo1302 thank you so far. I tried it like

>> pls check the updated question.

doesnt work for me?

Comment: how does the "close" class gets added to the button when you click on it?

Comment: @geo1302 sorry i forgot that - I've added the script to the footer, changed the document.querySelectorAll to a.menu-icon instead of button, but I am really realy not familar with JS - im more the backend type of person :S Thank you for your time, i realy appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle using CSS classes taken from the link you provided and some Javascript to add/remove the "close" class http://jsfiddle.net/3cc3T/6/ in order to obtain the animation

```
$(".lines-button").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
});
$(".exit-off-canvas").click(function(){
    $("#startupButton").removeClass("close");
});
```

Comment: I cant tell you how awesome you are, really. But it kinda works for me. The three lines are getting "smaller", the class is attached. But the lines it self wont animate. Your fiddle just gives me "text" as output.

Comment: Yeah I edited the link to show as little text as possible (the word "text" :)) as it might get distracting.
Could it be a browser issue that it's not working for you?

Comment: Could be, but I am getting crazy now.... after looking at it for hours im making it worse and worse :S I really dont know what I should do. the example still works for me so i guess its not the browser.

Comment: Perhaps you can post your code in a fiddle and i'll have a look at it

Comment: im on it, could take some time, also my first time over there, sorry! I tweeted you in the meantime.

Comment: in the meantime: The icon is now correct, it just dont transform (before i still had the original icon from foundation... so one step further... maybe i should quit and get another job :D

Comment: I am so sorry! It was my own fault -Ive been just looking at your new fiddle and deleted the JS that adds the close class, so now it works like a charm. You've spend an hour with my stupidity... don't know how i could thank you... YOU ARE AWESOME!